# How do i get my code to print one character name on seperate lines 10 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Ok so I'm writing a code that generates ten Dungeon and dragons characters. I need to generate ten characters, their should be one character on each line. Here's the instructions from my teacher: 
"Modify the program to generate 10 names and store them in an array. Then Write a function, dumpFile that writes the array to a file called "CharacterNames.txt"  There should be one Character Name on each line in the file."

So here's my original code.

```
import random

def main():

    txt1 = loadFile("names.txt")
    name_txt1 = random.randint(0, len(txt1))
    name2_txt1 = random.randint(0, len(txt1))
    txt2 = loadFile("titles.txt")
    titles_txt2 = random.randint(0, len(txt2))
    txt3 = loadFile("descriptors.txt")
    descriptors_txt3 = random.randint(0, len(txt3))

    print(txt2[titles_txt2], txt1[name_txt1], txt1[name2_txt1],"the", txt3[descriptors_txt3])

def loadFile(fileName):

    array = []
    file = open(fileName, "r")

    for line in file:
        array.append(line.strip())
    file.close()
    return(array)


main()
```

Here's my modified code so far.

```
import random


def main(): 
  txt1 = loadFile ("names.txt") 
  txt2 = loadFile ("titles.txt") 
  txt3 = loadFile ("descriptors.txt") 
  array = [] 

  for _ in range (10): 
    name_txt1 = dumpFile2 (txt1) 
    name2_txt1 = dumpFile2 (txt1) 
    titles_txt2 = dumpFile2 (txt2) 
    descriptors_txt3 = dumpFile2(txt3) 
    x = " ".join ((titles_txt2, name_txt1, name2_txt1, "the", descriptors_txt3)) 
    array.append (x.strip()) 
    dumpFile (array)

def loadFile (fileName): 
    with open (fileName) as file1: return file1.read ().splitlines () 


def dumpFile (arr): 
     file = open ("CharacterNames.txt", "w") 
     file.close()
     print(arr)

def dumpFile2(arr):
    return arr [random.randint(0, len(arr)- 1)]

main()
```

Here's the output I'm getting from my modified code:[This image shows the output I am getting from my modified code. I'm getting a bunch of lines when I'm supposed to only generate ten character names with one on each line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV97l.png)

Comment: You open the file and print the lines, but you never write them to the file.

Comment: You are calling dumpFile on every loop iteration, which is printing array for _ = 1, _ = 2, etc. Dedent the line dumpFile(array)

Comment: Thanks for bringing that too my attention , I originally had it out of the for loop but somehow didn't notice that I indented it back again. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dumpfile` is called in each iteration of your loop. Put it after the loop instead. In addition (as I'm sure you know), you are not reading to the file `dumpfile`, only printing to terminal.

You could do something like

```
names = '\n'.join(arr)
#print(names)
file.write(names)
```

before closing the file.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick , this answer my question ill be sure to give you the green check!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the default names on file "originalnames.txt", I would do something like this:

```
def readnames(file):
with open(file) as f:
    return f.read().splitlines()

def choosepos(max):
    from random import randint
    return randint(0, max-1)

def main():
    orignames = readnames('originalnames.txt')
    choosenames = list()
    for n in range(5): # number of names that you wnat
        npos = choosepos(len(orignames))
        print(npos)
        choosenames.append(orignames[npos])
        orignames.remove(orignames[npos]);
    # instead of print, you write on your file
    print(choosenames)

main()
```